# Are there any legitimate cases for presenting a UIAlertController from the Window's root?

Tags: swift, uiviewcontroller, uialertcontroller

Here, we have two ways to present a simple UIAlertController:

```
// In the context of a UIViewController
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
        
// Anywhere in the program
let alert = UIAlertController(title: "title", message: "message", preferredStyle: UIAlertController.Style.alert)
UIApplication.shared.keyWindow?.rootViewController?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Of course, when following an architecture like MVC, we don't want something in the model presenting a view (or in this case a `UIAlertController` that functions as a `UIView`). I was trying to think of good use cases for doing it the second way, but am having some difficulty. Is there some case perhaps now that we can support multiple `Window`s?

Answer (score 0):

to give you one example from an app I worked on years ago:

We used multiple `UIWindow` instances like you already mentioned.
Let's say an event in one window (`window1`) leads to the necessity to show an alert in another window (`window2`).

`window2` does not know which `UIView` is currently shown in `window1` and should not need to care. Instead if just sends out an event / notification / whatever that is caught bz `window1` which then just shows that alert from its `rootViewController` like you did in your example.

This is more an opinion than the `one and only` answer but your question was quite open anyway so I hope I can help you with that.

Cheers,
Dominic